# When should we use `expect` and when should we return error?

Tags: substrate

I saw many codes using `expect`. (In parity-bridges-common, frontier)

AFAIK the `expect` would cause a runtime panic.

And if we schedule a call that contains the `expect` part. That would break the chain.

Answer (score 0):

`expect` should only be use when the code is never expected to fail. If there is any possibility that it might fail than the error should be appropriately handled.